# responsive image and the tile not scaling properly in highresolution monitor and retina display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have large image similar to [this](http://kdmedia.kanald.ro/kfetele/image/201411/w650/media_141552418646507200.jpg). I need to put there images in bootstrap and align these to get layout similar to this. such that there tiles are arranged in a grid of 3 * 3. I was able to get these alignment with defult bootstrap classes like pull-right setting min width. but it does not show properly scale up in retina display and high resolution monitor how do I proceed using bootstrap 3. thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: the top square will have image that should be responsive

Answer (score 1):

Remove pull-right, min-width and put the image inside a bootstrap div with img-responsive class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            //your text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: since the image is very large how do I shrink it without height or width in normal screen since its is displayed big. while I want it to increase or decrease in size when seen in retina highres or in a normal phone according to resolution.

Comment: You could use 2 images. Larger one for desktops and a smaller one with 767px width for mobiles.

Comment: that is a good option but I have access to only one image how do I proceed

Comment: Then you should scale your image to a width that will look good on all devices. I'm not sure if there's another option when handling a single responsive image.

Comment: What if I give with and height in %

Comment: Then there is no point in using img-responsive bootstrap class. Refer this. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images